# Search For a Product on WooCommerce REST API v3 On NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, next.js, woocommerce

I want to be able to get results on the search for woocommerce products. I have the following

```js
const searchWooProducts = async (search, offset, limit = 10) => {
  const options = { search, 'per_page': limit, offset }

  return await WooCommerce.get(`products?search=${search}&offset=${offset}&limit=${limit}`)
    .then(res => {
      return res.data
    })
}
```

This always returns an empty array. This also is corroborated in postman using the same URI and basic auth with my key and secret. My question: Is this intended behavior or should I report this to Woocommerce?

Comment: FYI I am seeing in the headers that it is saying there are products being returned, and the number of pages they will have. But the issue is those results are not being returned.